# Доступ ssh из локальной сети в Виртуалку

Tags: ssh, администрирование

**имеется**: виртуальная машина VMWare с ОС Debian на борту, телефон (Android, клиент ssh - JuiceSSH и MobileSSH)

**Требуется**: Получить доступ ssh к Debian c телефона

**Данная схема** - ***тестовый*** стенд. Если все получится настроить по-человечески и не будет замечено никаких "багов" хочу перенести данную схему на работу для создания локального сервера.

Comment: Примечание: ОС хоста - Windows 8.1, если это имеет какое-то значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе в этом нет ничего сложного, данная схема вполне работоспособна. Пример настройки:

1. Хостовый компьютер подключен к WiFi роутеру (не принципиально, кабелем либо же по вайфаю)
2. Подключаете ваш телефон к этому-же роутеру.
3. ваша виртуалка с дебианом имеет сетевой интерфейс. В настройках этого интерфейса указываете режим `Bridged`
   [image: скриншот настроек VM]
4. В настройках сети на дебиане убедитесь что активно получение адресов по DHCP
5. Убеждаетесь в работоспособности и корректной конфигурации sshd
6. Командой `ifconfig` в дебиане либо же в админке роутера выясняете IP адрес вашей виртуальной машины.
7. В SSH клиенте на телефоне используете этот адрес для подключения

Comment: 1. Как консольно проверить активность получения адресов по dhcp

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`


Там должно быть вроде этого: `iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Comment: назрел еще один вопрос (данную схему на практике еще не проверил, домой приду - попробую)
в телефоне я ввожу ip адрес **виртуальной машины**? или адрес хостовой машины?



Изначально я думал поднять соединение с хост(windows) потом через нее подцепиться к виртуалке (Debian) или я неправильно думаю

Comment: Нет, в телефоне вы вводите адрес именно виртуалки. Она получит себе отдельный адрес от DHCP на роутере.